# API authentication in iframe

Tags: laravel, api, iframe

We are building a link/iframe that users can use on their website to post information to our CRM via our API. I want them to authenticate with their own API credentials. Im not sure how to fix this because they cant pass their API credentials (apikey) to the iframe. Every user has his own url like iframe.domain.com/{user_id}. Based on the user_id i want to authenticate the user but i want to avoid someone else can use that link too and abuse our API. We have API IP whitelisting but i cant use this because the remote IP will be the IP of who is submitting the form and not the server that is hosting the iframe/form.

How would you handle this? Hope someone can help me out.

In case its relevant: both are build in Laravel.

Raymond

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just give each user their own unique api-token? That way, each time a user accesses that URL, they have to put the token in the url (Like this : ?token="token")

Comment: Thank you Kneegrows! Every user has his own api key. But i want to keep that key private. If they use it public, someone else can copy the url and abuse our API and post a lot of crap to our CRM. Thats why i was wondering if i have other options :)

Comment: You could use Laravel auth package along with passport package if you want. That way, users have to add an Authorization header (Bearer token. The token is updated each time they login), and you can easily manage them from your side. I don't think it will be stolen in anyway, as the token is generated from your side and not theirs. They just have to login using your users table.

Answer (score -2):

I recently made my own NodeJS API for a mobile app. I used (JWT) JSON Web Token for the authentication. More details on the principle of use in this link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Ip0pcwbWYM
You should find a similar solution for Laravel with a Bearer auth.
I hope it can help you :-)